# Displaying a lot of locations that need to be geocoded on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am writing an Android app that would display "offers" people have made on a website on Google Map. I currently have 20-30k offers in database, but they are stored by address not by coordinates, so before displaying them on the Google Map I need to geocode the addresses to get coordinates. The location of offers will not change, so I would need to geocode every address only once.

Here's my problem. I need to geocode 20k addresses of offers already in database and all future offers (about 100/day). But after reading [The Google Geocoding API TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12) I realized that it is illegal to store geocoded results.

> Also note that the caching of geocoding results is only allowed for
>   the purpose of improving the performance of your application, and
>   cached results may not be stored for more than 30 days. For example,
>   you must not use the results to create an independent database of
>   places or other local listings information.

So my question is how should I approach this? I'd like to do the geocoding in server side and then send the coordinates of offers to the app for displaying. Geocoding all the addresses client-side would be way too slow and kinda pointless, because the addresses never change.

If I save geocoded coordinates server-side would this fall under the

> caching of geocoding results is only allowed for the purpose of
>   improving the performance of your application

clause in Google Maps TOS?

Answer (score 1):

how about using http://geocoder.opencagedata.com/api.html
they allow caching for unlimited time as of now.